# Creating Python RPM

Tags: python, linux, rpm, rpmbuild, checkinstall

I have been reading about creating an RPM for Python 2.6.4. In this page: http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html it says you can create an RPM of the current Python using `python setup.py bdist_rpm`. The question's I have are:

- Do you have to type this command in your Python installation directory?
- Does this command, package all the modules you have installed into the RPM?
- Is this the correct command to do this?
- Are there any other suggestion's that would make this easier?

---

Okay I sorted this out using checkinstall.

I downloaded `checkinstall` from http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/.

I then installed the package but had to enter `/usr/local/sbin/checkinstall` into my PATH to make it work. I then entered the next copmmand to get my RPM directory going.

```
 yum install rpm-build
```

I then `cd` into the Python module and entered this command:

```
 checkinstall -R --nodoc --delspec=no  --exclude=/selinux python2.6 ./setup.py install
```

This command replaces the command `checkinstall` as your installing python libraries through setup.py instead of an ordinary make.

I then went through the `checkinstall` process. The finished RPM was placed into `/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386/`.

Note: THIS IS FOR LINUX RED HAT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This command has to be typed wherever your `setup.py` is located.
2. It packages everything that would show up in a `bdist` tarball.
3. Err... sort of. While it works, the package it creates is not of very high quality. It's better to use `sdist_rpm`, then unpack the resulting SRPM and then apply your distro's [Python packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python) to the generated spec file.
4. Get it to work via `bdist` first. That way any issues that crop up will be more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

These instructions explain how to create an RPM package for your module. As far as I know, there is no (easy) way to package all your Python installation into an RPM.

If you want to create an RPM package to install Python 2.6.4 on an older distro, you download the Python 2.6.4 source RPM and then rebuild it with `rpmbuild`. See [Fedora RPM Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/drafts/rpm-guide-en/).