# Python- Build rpm for a django project

Tags: python, django

I have a django project which i want to distribute to another machine(Linux). That machine doesn't have python, django or any other dependent libraries. I wanted to create a standalone setup for django project so that i can run my site created in django on that Linux machine. So how would i be able to build rpm setup for Linux?????

I have already read:
1. [How to distribute Python/Django App via RPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225906/how-to-distribute-python-django-app-via-rpm)
2. http://www.morethanseven.net/2011/01/29/Using-checkinstall-with-virtualenv-for-python-deployments/

But nothing helped so far..

Answer (score 0):

Few weeks ago make presentation [Build Python-project](https://speakerdeck.com/toidi/sborka-python-proiekta)

Unfortunately it only in Russian language.

Look at slides and you are welcome questions.