# Specifying installation path of python modules from installed RPM

Tags: python, linux, module, rpm, rhel

I have a simple python script that I have been trying to package into an RPM. This was a simple python script that you can run by calling "./". However, to package it into an RPM, I turned the script into a module with a **init**.py and setup.py. I was able to package it into an rpm using "python setup.py bdist_rpm" following https://docs.python.org/2.0/dist/creating-rpms.html . I was also able to install the created .noarch.rpm file into a different machine. However, I have no idea how to use this script now after I installed the .noarch.rpm file.

So, I successfully installed the .noarch.rpm file that has my script packaged into it, but I have no idea where this file is or how to use my script from this. This is my very first time creating an RPM, and I am fairly new to Python as well, so I think I am just missing something. Is there a way to specify where the python module is installed when I install the .noarch.rpm?

I am running on RHEL. I also looked at two other StackExchange questions/answers that are similar to what I want, but I still do not quite understand what to do. Here are the other questions/answers:  [Python distutils - Change Path RPM Installs To](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411602/python-distutils-change-path-rpm-installs-to)       and     [Creating Python RPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324933/creating-python-rpm)

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of files in your RPM package by:

```
rpm -qpl ./some_package.rpm
```

or when already installed:

```
rpm -ql some_package
```